# Adding an extra thumb to a slider in Avalonia C#

Tags: c#, slider, avaloniaui, avalonia

I want to add a Thumb to make a Slider like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArAPb.png
And currently I have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArAPb.png

I have the impression that natively Avalonia doesn't allow to simply add a Thumb
The goal is that the user can choose a minimum and maximum value among a range of values that I will have defined manually in the code

Here is how I create my Slider in axaml file:

```
<Slider Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="65, 0, 0, 0" Height="35" Width="150" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="50" />
```